# ArrayList returning null from firebase array adapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, arraylist, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to add the data that I got from the `datasnapshot` into an `arraylist` but it keeps returning `null`. I know I should be doing any changes to UI inside of this method however I need to be able to access this outside of the method so I can return the value back to my fragment.

I have added print statements inside the `datasnapshot` and I can see that I am getting the data I need however outside of the scope of the `@Override` function it remains empty. I need a way to access this globally to send to my `arrayAdapter` and return my other activity which implements this fragment. Please help.

```
public class YourTripTab extends Fragment {

    private DatabaseReference userReference;
    private String userID;
    private String Tag = "YourTripTab";
    private List<Trip> trips = new ArrayList<>();

    public void setUserID(String userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View tripView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_trips, container, false);

        userReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("userTrips").child(userID);

        //find Id from xml file
        ListView tripListView = (ListView) tripView.findViewById(R.id.trips);

        //create our TripListAdapter array adapter
        TripListAdapter tripListAdapter = new TripListAdapter(getContext(), retrieve());

        tripListView.setAdapter(tripListAdapter);

        return tripView;

    }

    public List<Trip> retrieve() {

        userReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String startDate = ds.child("startDate").getValue().toString();
                        String tripName = ds.child("tripName").getValue().toString();
                        System.out.println("Trip Name:~ " + ds.getKey() + ":: startDate here ~ " + startDate + "//" + "tripName ~ " + tripName);
                        trips.add(new Trip(tripName, startDate));
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                //no data exists or error getting data
            }

        });

        System.out.println("Here is the size of trips list: " + trips.size());

        return trips;
    }

}
```

**EDIT**

I managed to fix it here is the solution

````
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {


        final View tripView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_trips, container, false);



        getData(new FirebaseCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCallBack(List<Trip> list) {
                for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
                    trips.add(list.get(i));
                }
                tripListView = (ListView) tripView.findViewById(R.id.trips);
                tripListAdapter = new TripListAdapter(getContext(), trips);
                tripListView.setAdapter(tripListAdapter);
            }
        });



        return tripView;

    }


    private interface FirebaseCallback {

        void onCallBack(List<Trip> list);

    }


    private void getData(final FirebaseCallback firebaseCallback) {

        userReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("userTrips").child(userID);
        userReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    List<Trip> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
                    System.out.println("dataSnapshot is here: " + dataSnapshot);

                    for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        String startDate = snapshot.child("startDate").getValue().toString();
                        String tripName = snapshot.child("tripName").getValue().toString();
                        System.out.println("startDate here: " + startDate + "\n" + "tripName: " + tripName);
                        tempList.add(new Trip(tripName, startDate));

                    }

                    firebaseCallback.onCallBack(tempList);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }```
````

Comment: from where you are calling `transferData` method in your code?

Comment: Ah let me edit that I was trying something earlier and it wasn't working. I forgot to take it out

Comment: You can also check **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47847694/how-to-return-datasnapshot-value-as-a-result-of-a-method/47853774)** out.

Comment: OMG thank you so much this fixed it. I'm gonna show my edited code. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`addValueEventListener` is asynchronous and returns immediately.  The callback you passed to it will get invoked some unknown amount of time later, whenever the data is available.  This means that your `retrieve` method also returns immediately with the initial value of `trips`, which is empty.  To state this another way - the first time `retrieve` is called, it returns an empty List of Trip objects.

If you want your ListView to show data, you should instead set its adapter *after* you've collected all this trips.  This means you should do it inside the `addValueEventListener` callback.

Comment: So are you suggesting I put the tripListAdapter in the onDataChange function? Also sorry if any of this sounds dumb I'm still learning android.

Comment: That is one way to do it.

Comment: Ok so I basically put these 2 lines here 
TripListAdapter tripListAdapter = new TripListAdapter(getContext(), retrieve());
& tripListView.setAdapter(tripListAdapter), inside of the override method but it still tells me the list trips.size is 0;